# Request by docName in python from Oracle UCM

Tags: oracle, soap, python-requests

Connecting to oracle UCM by python, I have to automate this process on schedules we create. I hence need to download Manifest.MF for the list of Doc Ids. When I create the request body for DocID, it downloads data perfectly. However, when I give the doc Name (Manifest.MF), and define the format as requestbody.format(DocName='') it gives me the error. "Unable to download file, Unable to retrieve information for 'MANIFEST"., I still get a 200 response.

what possible solutions for this?